# return function pointer error without typedef?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a function, which can return "malloc" function pointer.

But there's an error, the platform is Windows 7 + Visual Studio 2015.

source code "malloc.cpp":

```
#include <cstdlib>


namespace portable {

    static void *(*malloc_impl)(size_t) = std::malloc;
    static void (*free_impl)(void*) = std::free;
    static void *(*realloc_impl)(void*, size_t) = std::realloc;
    static void *(*calloc_impl)(size_t, size_t) = std::calloc;

#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(__MINGW32__)
#   error("sorry, we don't support MinGW32 compiler with Windows")
#endif

#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(_MSC_VER)
#   include <WinSock2.h>
#   include <Windows.h>
    static size_t (*malloc_usable_size_impl)(void*) = _msize;
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#   include <malloc.h>
    static size_t (*malloc_usable_size_impl)(void*) = malloc_size;
#else
#   include <malloc.h>
    static size_t (*malloc_usable_size_impl)(void*) = malloc_usable_size;
#endif

    void *( *o_set_malloc( void *(*func)(size_t) ) ) (size_t) throw()
    {
        void *(*old)(size_t) = malloc_impl;
        if (func) {
            malloc_impl = func;
        }
        return old;
    }
    size_t ( *o_set_malloc_usable_size( size_t (*func)(void*) ) ) (void*) throw()
    {
        size_t (*old)(void*) = malloc_usable_size_impl;
        if (func) {
            malloc_usable_size_impl = func;
        }
        return old;
    }
    void ( *o_set_free( void (*func)(void*) ) ) (void*) throw()
    {
        void (*old)(void*) = free_impl;
        if (func) {
            free_impl = func;
        }
        return old;
    }
    void *( *o_set_realloc( void *(*func)(void*, size_t) ) ) (void*, size_t) throw()
    {
        void *(*old)(void*, size_t) = realloc_impl;
        if (func) {
            realloc_impl = func;
        }
        return old;
    }
    void *( *o_set_calloc( void *(*func)(size_t, size_t) ) ) (size_t, size_t) throw()
    {
        void *(*old)(size_t, size_t) = calloc_impl;
        if (func) {
            calloc_impl = func;
        }
        return old;
    }
}
```

the compiler report error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)

incompatible exception specifications

d:\work\project\orange\src\portable\malloc.cpp  56

It seems "old" is not compatible with return type. please help me.

Comment: A [mcve] would be rather helpful. I can't reproduce any compiler error on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/.

Answer (score -1):

thanks the comments, I find the problem.

On Windows 7 + VS2015, I defined something like:

```
#define NOEXCEPT throw()
```

the incompatible is between "`void *(*)(size_t)`" and "`void *(*)(size_t) throw()`".